# Scheme for Apple Map in iOS 6: how to show a callout/pin?

Tags: ios, dictionary

With google map I can do:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=[Title]@[Lat,Lon]

which will show a pin on that geolocation, but in Apple's doc:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

there is no way to do this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The closest I've found is the MKMapItem class method openMapsWithItems. You can use that to drop one or more pins into the maps application, and optionally show directions between 2 points. However, I cant figure out how to add a title the pin that you add.

Comment: I've got the same issue.  Is there any way to do this without MKMap?   I'd way rather not bring it in if I can avoid it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)create_Map{


    for (int i=0; i<[arrayMap count]; i++) {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
        theCoordinate1.latitude =[[[arrayMap objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
        theCoordinate1.longitude =[[[arrayMap objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
        addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate1];
        addAnnotation.mTitle=[[arrayMap objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"place"];
        [_locMapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

    }



    NSArray *coordinates = [_locMapView valueForKeyPath:@"annotations.coordinate"];
    // look for the minimum and maximum coordinate
    NSLog(@"coordinates     %@ %i ",coordinates,[arrayMap count]);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D maxCoord = {-90.0f, -180.0f};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D minCoord = {90.0f, 180.0f};
    for(NSValue *value in coordinates) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {0.0f, 0.0f};
        [value getValue:&coord];
        if(coord.longitude > maxCoord.longitude) {
            maxCoord.longitude = coord.longitude;

            NSLog(@"maxCoord.longitude     %f  ",maxCoord.longitude);
        }
        if(coord.latitude > maxCoord.latitude) {
            maxCoord.latitude = coord.latitude;
        }
        if(coord.longitude < minCoord.longitude) {
            minCoord.longitude = coord.longitude;
        }
        if(coord.latitude < minCoord.latitude) {
            minCoord.latitude = coord.latitude;
        }
    }
    // create a region
     MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
    region.center.longitude = (minCoord.longitude + maxCoord.longitude) / 2.0;
    region.center.latitude = (minCoord.latitude + maxCoord.latitude) / 2.0;
    // calculate the span
    region.span.longitudeDelta = maxCoord.longitude - minCoord.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = maxCoord.latitude - minCoord.latitude;

    [_locMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

   // [_locMapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
  //  [_locMapView regionThatFits:region];


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do indeed use the MKMapItem class method openMapsWithItems.

The trick is that MKMapItem objects have a name property. If you set the name property on the MKMapItem object(s) that you pass to openMapsWithItems, those items get named in the map when it's opened.

So the steps are:

Create an MKPlacemark for your pin. You can provide lat/long coordinates, or address information.

Create an MKMapItem from your placemark
Set the name property on your map item.

Call `[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:]` to open the maps app and drop a pin at the specified location. Note that you can use this call to drop more than one pin, or to provide walking or driving directions between two points.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_transaction.lat.doubleValue, _transaction.lon.doubleValue);

MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
mapItem.name = _transaction.merchant_name;
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey : @(MKMapTypeStandard),
                                       MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey : @YES}];
```